# Best position for a voucher code box in the checkout process

Tags: e-commerce, checkout, vouchers

Checkout processes are usually fairly complicated things, but each one has a very similar set of core steps, such as a header basket summary and some full checkout pages (basket, address and payment for example), often with some sort of summary of the basket visible on all the full checkout pages.

Of the common steps of a checkout process which would be the best place to display a voucher code field, when considering the ease of use and feedback for the user as well as the potential effect on conversions while also assuming any entered value is easily remembered between pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You normally see them in the step where the price is summed up.

> Price product + btw + shipping cost = price total

It's an adjustment to the price so it would be logical to let people enter it in this step.

> Price product + btw + shipping cost - voucher = price total

Answer (score 1):

The best place for voucher/discount code depends on the flow you have.

If you have many steps and users is buying products *because* he has a discount code then you display this field as early as possible - at 1st step. So a user can see that codes are accepted and hence he continues the checkout process.

Further you can apply this code's discount to the total price - no problem.

IF you have just one payment form (credit card) you can display the discount field right after credit card information - no need to be afraid he will not see the discount field.

Comment: I've designed a few checkouts and agree with your answer, the first step is often a good place - often below the products and above the total and the button to the next step. But as you rightly say, it depends.